# joining two tables with differnt join column names

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm, join, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables A -> B with many-to-one mapping/associations.

Table B's primary key is foreign key in table A.

The problem is column names in both tables are different. let's say B has primary  key column "typeNumId" which is foreign key in table A as "type". How can I join both tables on this column? how can I specify mapping to indicate that tables have to join on "typeNumId" and "type" which is essentially same.

especially is this possible through hibernate config ( hbm files) ?

something like

```
<many-to-one name="Type" class="com.domain.ProcedureType" update="false" insert="false" fetch="join" lazy="false">
    <column name="? <this is in questions? >" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

Comment: I think you lost most of your XML example to html stripping, try indenting it four spaces (or click the "code" button).

Answer (score 3):

The ON clause:

```
select * from A join B on A.type = B.typeNumId
```

Comment: Actually, I understand the question as being about how to write the mapping.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: Definitely.  I answered the q before it included any mention of Hibernate, and as I don't know Hibernate, I couldn't really re-answer ... ;)

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't notice the OP updated the question. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the name of the foreign key using the `column` attribute of the `many-to-one` element or the equivalnent nested `column` element. From the documentation:

> #### 5.1.12. Many-to-one
>
> An ordinary association to another
>   persistent class is declared using a
>   many-to-one element. The relational
>   model is a many-to-one association; a
>   foreign key in one table is
>   referencing the primary key column(s)
>   of the target table.
>
> ```
> <many-to-one
>         name="propertyName"                                          (1)
>         column="column_name"                                         (2)
>         class="ClassName"                                            (3)
>         cascade="cascade_style"                                      (4)
>         fetch="join|select"                                          (5)
>         update="true|false"                                          (6)
>         insert="true|false"                                          (6)
>         property-ref="propertyNameFromAssociatedClass"               (7)
>         access="field|property|ClassName"                            (8)
>         unique="true|false"                                          (9)
>         not-null="true|false"                                        (10)
>         optimistic-lock="true|false"                                 (11)
>         lazy="proxy|no-proxy|false"                                  (12)
>         not-found="ignore|exception"                                 (13)
>         entity-name="EntityName"                                     (14)
>         formula="arbitrary SQL expression"                           (15)
>         node="element-name|@attribute-name|element/@attribute|."
>         embed-xml="true|false"
>         index="index_name"
>         unique_key="unique_key_id"
>         foreign-key="foreign_key_name"
> />
> ```
>
> 1. name: the name of the property.
> 2. column (optional): the name of the foreign key column. This can also be
>      specified by nested 
>      element(s).
> 3. class (optional - defaults to the property type determined by
>      reflection): the name of the
>      associated class.
> 4. cascade (optional): specifies which operations should be cascaded from the
>      parent object to the associated
>      object.
> 5. fetch (optional - defaults to select): chooses between outer-join
>      fetching or sequential select
>      fetching.
> 6. update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the mapped
>      columns should be included in SQL
>      UPDATE and/or INSERT statements.
>      Setting both to false allows a pure
>      "derived" association whose value is
>      initialized from another property that
>      maps to the same column(s), or by a
>      trigger or other application.
> 7. property-ref (optional): the name of a property of the associated class
>      that is joined to this foreign key. If
>      not specified, the primary key of the
>      associated class is used.
> 8. access (optional - defaults to property): the strategy Hibernate uses
>      for accessing the property value.
> 9. unique (optional): enables the DDL generation of a unique constraint for
>      the foreign-key column. By allowing
>      this to be the target of a
>      property-ref, you can make the
>      association multiplicity one-to-one.
> 10. not-null (optional): enables the DDL generation of a nullability
>       constraint for the foreign key
>       columns.
> 11. optimistic-lock (optional - defaults to true): specifies that
>       updates to this property do or do not
>       require acquisition of the optimistic
>       lock. In other words, it determines if
>       a version increment should occur when
>       this property is dirty.
> 12. lazy (optional - defaults to proxy): by default, single point
>       associations are proxied.
>       lazy="no-proxy" specifies that the
>       property should be fetched lazily when
>       the instance variable is first
>       accessed. This requires build-time
>       bytecode instrumentation. lazy="false"
>       specifies that the association will
>       always be eagerly fetched.
> 13. not-found (optional - defaults to exception): specifies how foreign keys
>       that reference missing rows will be
>       handled. ignore will treat a missing
>       row as a null association.
> 14. entity-name (optional): the entity name of the associated class.
> 15. formula (optional): an SQL expression that defines the value for
>       a computed foreign key.

So something like this should do it:

```
<many-to-one name="Type" class="com.domain.ProcedureType" update="false" insert="false" fetch="join" lazy="false">
    <column name="type" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core documenation

  - [5.1.12. Many-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
LEFT JOIN B on A.field1 = B.field2
```

Choose type of JOIN on your taste